# Linked list showing cannot convert pointer to void

Tags: c, linked-list

```
  if (option == 1)
        {
           pointer temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Customer));

            printf("Input PPS\n");
            scanf("%d", &temp->PPS);
            if (checkPPS(temp->PPS))
            {
                printf("PPS already exist\n");
                printf("Input PPS\n");
                scanf("%d", &temp->PPS);
            }
            printf("Input LOGIN\n");
            scanf("%s", temp->login);
            printf("Input PASSWORD atleast 6 digits long\n");
            scanf("%d", &temp->password);
            printf("Input firstname\n");
            scanf("%s", temp->firstname);
            printf("Input lastname\n");
            scanf("%s", temp->lastname);
            printf("Input yearborn\n");
            scanf("%d", &temp->yearborn);
            printf("Input email address\n");
            scanf("%s", temp->emailaddress);
            printf("Input AREA\n");
            scanf("%d", &temp->area);
            printf("Input TICKET TYPE\n");
            scanf("%d", &temp->TT);

            AddCustomer(temp, l);
        }
```

> So heres the problem I've tried looking at whats wrong but i cant figure out why as when I try to run it it keeps showing me an error that initializing cannot convert void to pointer

Comment: What is the exact error message, and what line is it happening on? Can you simplify your example and remove all the code unrelated to the error?

Comment: Get out of the habit of creating pointer typedefs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers

Comment: Cannot reproduce. That line doesn't produce a warning or error when I compile the code with clang.

Comment: Ok ill edit it now and show you the problem